# decrement prefix as condition in c while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

Concerning the following usage, i'm confused how --i evaluates to true and what determines when the loop exits:

```
while (--i) {
    k = p[i];
    p[i] = p[j = random() % B];
    p[j] = k;
}
```

if as I understand it the -- prefix is decrementing the value of i before it begins the loop, are we then evaluating true=value > 1 and false=0 and thus the loop exits when the value reaches 0? Perhaps I've answered my own question, but if anyone could enlighten me on this. Also, how would this loop behave if the decrement operator was a suffix?

Comment: Have you *tried* it with post-decrement (`i--`)?

Comment: Indeed -- in _C_ a value of zero (0) causes a condition test to evaluate as _false_, and any other value is treated as _true_ (including negative values, in the case of signed integers)

Comment: @casperone, can you suggest a way to improve this question? I don't see how, plus the fact that it was answered would tend to indicate that you are incorrect that it is not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, prefix decrement will decrement the variable, then the returned value (the *result*) from the expression is used for the condition.

The loop terminates when `i` becomes `1` (and it decremented to `0`, the returned value of the condition).

Comment: to be clear it's not a "return" value, but rather the _result_ value, the result of evaluating the expression.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Thanks, I chose a word that would hopefully be clearer to a beginner, but now I see the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined your code i can say that it totally depends on the value of i.
**if the value of i=0 initially then it will go in infinite loop** because **--i** will become **-1** which will be true condition for the while loop.

so **if the value of i is other than 0 (may be positive or negative) then it will always true but when it will become 0 the loop will terminate**

and for prefix & suffix ... u should remember that in **(-- variable) or (++ variable) case the variable will be incremented or decremented first then checked but in (variable --) or (variable ++) case the variable will be incremented or decremented later but checked first**